# Python sqlalchemy catch sql message

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Working with Python and SQL Server I'm trying to catch the SQL Messages (PRINT or RAISERROR) that may ossure when exeuting SQL command or stored procedure.

On the SQL Server I have the following procedure (simplified for my question)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pyTest (@n int)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tablename') IS NULL RAISERROR(N'Error. Destination table not found.',0,0) 
ELSE INSERT INTO dbo.tablename VALUES (@n);
```

In Python I'm executing this script

```
server = 'server_name'
db = 'database_name'
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{db}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
query="INSERT INTO dbo.tablename VALUES (1)"
#query="SELECT GETDATE()"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(query)
```

**My question is: How do I catch the messages being produced from the stored procedure?**

When I execute "EXEC dbo.pyTest 1" in SSMS 
I get the following text in the Messages tab 
"Error. Destination table not found."

But when I do the same in Python I get "Process finished with exit code 0"

I have been reading a lot of suggestions from Goggle, but have not been able to find similar question.

Comment: A [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) with severity level 0 is pretty much equivalent to a `PRINT` statement. Consider also that new applications should use [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql) instead.

Comment: That does not sound right - but never the less my question does not directly consern RAISERROR, PRINT (or THROW)*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
The THROW command is related to TRY-CATCH
Thanks for your comment